# NSAttributedString initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error: documentAttributes not retained in ARC

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to load documents from `NSData` (it's from a `Dropbox` file in my app, but for simplicity sake, the example below uses a .txt file, which causes the same issue I'm trying to fix).

Problem:
I instantiate an NSDictionary, and pass it to `[NSAttributedString -initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:]`as an out parameter.

However, the NSDictionary instance gets deallocated, and causes -initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error: to crash.

When I enable `NSZombie`, the error I get is: [__NSDictionaryI retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

-`initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:` runs fine when I pass NULL to documentAttributes.

Here's the code:

```
NSError* error;
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Forward Thinking"
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:&error];
if (data) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSDictionary* documentAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        NSAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:nil documentAttributes:&documentAttributes error:NULL];
        self.textView.attributedText = attrStr;
    });
}
```

Any leads would be great!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not allocate the `NSDictionary` you pass to this method. What you want is:

```
NSDictionary* documentAttributes;
NSAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:nil documentAttributes:&documentAttributes error:NULL];
```

It is passing `documentAttributes` to *you*. You don't pass the attributes to it.